# Trying to display data from two tables

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to `$_GET` data from one table based on the id found in the other table. My first table is called `user_thoughts`, this table holds the data off all the public posts users make on my "social media website". I have another table called `users` which, stores all the details of the registered users for the site.

I am trying to display all the `user_thoughts` on the homepage of the website, but I am struggling to display the correct data for the author of the "thought".

The idea is to get the `added_by` (author) of the `user_thought` then using the variable holding the value of `added_by` and comparing it to the `username` found in table `users`.

Here are my table's and it's fields:

**`user_thoughts`**:

```
id
message
date_of_msg_post
time_of_msg_post
attachment
added_by
```

**`users`** (Just displaying the relevant fields)

```
id
first_name
last_name
username
profile_pic
```

**Aim**:Get the added_by of the post from `user_thoughts`, then use added_by to get the added_by's details from the username field in table `users`. Note: added_by and username both will hold the same value.

**Here is what I have tried**:

```
/* How it works: The id of each user_thought will be used to determine which user posted it. 
 * Then display their details accourdingly.
 */
$get_thoughts_from_db = mysqli_query($connect, "SELECT * FROM user_thoughts ORDER BY id DESC"); // newest posts first

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($get_thoughts_from_db)) {
    $thought_id      = $row['id'];
    $msg_content     = $row['message'];
    $date_of_msg     = $row['date_of_msg_post'];
    $thoughts_by     = $row['added_by'];
    $time_of_msg     = $row['time_of_msg_post'];
    $attachent       = $row['attachment'];
    $get_user        = $_GET['id'];
} // while closed   

    // Get the details of the user based on the ID of the user thought.
    $get_data = mysqli_query($connect, "SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = '$get_user'");                                   
    $get_user_data = mysqli_fetch_assoc($get_data);
        $author_fname = $get_user_data['first_name'];
        $user_profile_dp = $get_user_data['profile_pic'];

// displaying all the posts in the database on the main page.
// Will limit 15 posts per page, and will order them by the date and time posted (latest posts first)
$get_all_posts_q = mysqli_query ($connect, "SELECT * FROM user_thoughts ORDER BY id DESC ");
    $check_rows = mysqli_num_rows($get_all_posts_q);
    while ($get_row = mysqli_fetch_array($get_all_posts_q)){
        $message         = $get_row['message']; 

        /**** Between the while loop is where I echo the div(s)
                     which display the above details. *******/

}
```

**Current behavior:**
At the moment, with the code above, it displays all the `user_thoughts`, i.e. there are three rows in the table, and each one is being displayed, however, the details along it are not based on the author of those posts. For example, the profile_pic of the user who wrote the author is not displaying.

Comment: you are vulnerable to [sql injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com). and note that you're fetching your user_thoughts results in a loop, but you don't use those results until AFTER the loop finishes, so you only ever use the LAST thought you fetched.

Comment: Are you trying to show a list of thoughts from a single user, or a list of thoughts from all users?

Comment: @OscarJ - Every single row in the user_thoughts table should be displayed on the homepage. So to answer your question, all users.

Comment: @MarcB - You're right, but with the while loop as depicted in the question, all the thoughts are being depicted? I did have a prior problems where one "thought" was displayed three times (as there are three rows in user_thoughts table), but with the while loop, all the posts now show.

Comment: what you really should be doing is using a single `JOIN`ed query. anytime you have nested queries, and the inner query depends on data from the outer query, they probably can/should be rewritten as a single join.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This links the users and the user_thoughts. Remember to sanitize your inputs.

```
$get_thoughts_from_db = mysqli_query($connect, "SELECT * FROM user_thoughts INNER JOIN users ON user_thoughts.added_by = users.username ON ORDER BY id DESC"); // newest posts first
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$query = <<<EOD
    SELECT t.id AS tid, u.id AS uid, * FROM user_thoughts AS t, users AS u
    WHERE t.added_by=u.id ORDER BY t.id DESC
EOD;

$result = mysqli_query($connect, $query);

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $thought_id      = $row['tid'];
    $msg_content     = $row['message'];
    $date_of_msg     = $row['date_of_msg_post'];
    $thoughts_by     = $row['added_by'];
    $time_of_msg     = $row['time_of_msg_post'];
    $attachment       = $row['attachment'];
    $author_fname    = $row['first_name'];
    $user_profile_dp = $row['profile_pic'];

    // echo your div
}
```